# adfs asking admin credentials why?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sharepoint, adfs

Iam working as a system admin, my company got the sharepoint project.
So we need to install sharepoint server with ADFS configuration. 
But why ADFS asking domain administrator password during the installation?

Could we install Sharepoint server with ADFS in our existing production active directory environment?  Is this advisable.

Answer (score 1):

It is need to do some specific settings within the ActiveDirectory like setup of the GroupManagedServiceAccount (gMSA), creation of custom Containers etc.

There is the option to do the installation [without Domain-Admin-Permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/install-ad-fs-delegated-admin) but i would not recommend it. For the manual preparation tasks you will also need the Admin-Permissions to do it.

Comment: Note that you still need someone with domain admin privs to perform some steps, it just doesn't have to be the same person that installs Adfs in 2016.